# How to add image to Power BI Card

Tags: powerbi

I want to add an image to power bi Card

I just want to add an image ( not from data source )

[image]

I checked all Card properties but I could not find any image property!!

so how can I add an image to my card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do it with the standard visual, however you can do it with the custom plugin '[Infographic Designer](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380898?tab=Overview)'. This is a Microsoft developed plugin that can create a nicely formatted card visual, with background images and better text alignment.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add an image to the report from `Insert` -> `Image` ribbon command:

[image]

Place it next to the card, and for convenience you can group it with it:

[image]

The inconvenience here is that the image will not move when the width of the card value change.